# Spotfire 7 filter table after clicking dynamic value

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am looking for a way to filter a table based on clicking a dynamic value in a Textarea in Spotfire 7.0.

I have a Textarea with an image and a bunch of calculated values over the top of that image (essentially a non geographic "map" of values). I would like to filter a table to show the rows which contribute to that dynamic value.

How can I filter the table based on the value clicked in the Textarea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spotfire bookmarks. Create bookmarks and then configure images as a buttons and apply click action on them to redirect user to the particular bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply marking on Calculated values in a way that you can set your child visualizations to be limited by your dynamic value marking.